# How to play .pls playlist url with MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, playlist, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have a live radio streaming playlist url, when I open that url in UIWebView, the app automatically opens a player looks like MPMoviePlayer, not sure what player it is, but it plays iPod with the streaming. I was able to set volume up/down with 
    [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setVolume:volume];

I wanted to do all with MPMusicPlayerController so that I can control the streaming in my app.
  I tried creating MPMediaItemCollection with the URL and set it to the MusicController, but it didn't work.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first parse the .pls file then play it.

Have a look at https://github.com/drodriguez/globradio/blob/master/Classes/RRQPLSParser.m for parsing, and at the entire project for playing.

To play a streaming audio, however, this project is more recent: https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

Hope this helps.